# surface area as double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand the formula for surface area of $z=f(x,y)$ as given 
$S = \int\int_A \sqrt{1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2} dA$.

In the derivation it says the small portion (above the area $dA_i$) of the tangent plane to the surface is a parallelogram. And its sides are 
$\textbf{u} = \Delta x_i \;i + f_x(x_i,y_i)\Delta x_i \; k$

$\textbf{v} = \Delta y_i \;j + f_y(x_i,y_i)\Delta y_i \; k$.

I am not getting how these vectors are the sides of that parallelogram.

thanks

Comment: sorry. now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As seen on the picture there are 4 points on the parallelogram above the unit area $dA_{ij}$. These points are

$A = (x_i,y_j,f(x_i,y_j)$.

$B = (x_{i+1},y_j,f(x_{i+1},y_j))$.

$C = (x_i,y_{j+1},f(x_i,y_{j+1}))$.

$D = (x_{i+1},y_{j+1},f(x_{i+1},y_{j+1}))$.

We can find the 2 sides $|AB| & |AC|$ by substructing their coordinates

$|AB| = B-A = (x_{i+1}-x_i , 0 , f(x_{i+1},y_j)-f(x_i,y_j)) = (\Delta{X_i}, 0 , f_x(x_i,y_j)*\Delta{X_i} )$
$|AC| = C-A = (0 , y_{j+1}-y_j , f(x_i,y_{j+1})-f(x_i,y_j)) = (0 , \Delta{Y_j}, 0 , f_y(x_i,y_j)*\Delta{Y_j} )$